# Change position QVBoxLayout Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I have QGraphicsView and QVBoxLayout on QMainWindow. I want to change QVBoxLayout position, when user want to resize window, and QGraphicsView must stay.

Trying to use QMainWindow::resizeEvent:

```
 void Interface::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
    {
        QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
        if (this)
        {
            QRect temp(ui.interfaceLayout->geometry());
            ui.interfaceLayout->setGeometry(QRect(event->size().width() - temp.width(), 
                                temp.top(), temp.width(), temp.height()));
        }
    }
```

When i'm trying to resize, all layout disappears.

Comment: This question is missing a [mcve]. And what is `if (this)` supposed to do, except for being equivalent to `if(true)` and thus needless?